# JavaScript Regex String with one asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string hast 0...n whitespace, one * and 0...n whitespace.

The pattern

```
 var derefpatt = new RegExp("\\s*\\*\\s*");  
 var res2 = derefpatt.test(string);
```

is true if string is "   **   " but it should be only true if string is "   *  "

What is wrong?

Regards

Alex

Comment: is n the same for both whitespace ?

Answer (score 2):

For:

- `0...n whitespace` -> `\s*`
- `one *` -> `\*`
- `0...n whitespace` -> `\s*`

You can use this regex (notice the usage of anchors `^` and `$`):

```
^\s*\*\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

On the other hand, if you want the same amount of spaces, you can use:

```
^(\s*)\*\1$
```

Comment: Thanks... var derefpatt = new RegExp("^\\s*\\*\\s*$");  works. But why "\\s*\\*\\s*" without ^ and $ doesn't work?

Comment: Because RegExp.test() doesn't check whether the whole string matches, it checks for any substring within the string that matches and returns true if it finds any. Since there are 0 characters of whitespace between the asterisks, it fulfills the condition of 0 characters of whitespace after an asterisk.